# Moving text inside canvas using html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to html5 development could anyone tell me how to make text to move one side to other horizontally inside canvas..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how to animate text back and forth across the screen:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>HTML 5 Animated Text</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var context;
        var text = "";
        var textDirection ="";

        $(function()
        {
            context = document.getElementById("cvs").getContext("2d");            
            setInterval("animate()", 30);

            textDirection ="right";
            textXpos = 5;
            text = "Animation!";    
        });  

        function animate() {            
            // Clear screen
            context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            context.globalAlpha = 1;
            context.fillStyle = '#fff';
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);    

            var metrics = context.measureText(text);
            var textWidth = metrics.width;

            if (textDirection == "right") {
                textXpos += 10;

                if (textXpos > 500 - textWidth) {
                    textDirection = "left";
                }
            }
            else {
                textXpos -= 10;

                if (textXpos < 10) {
                    textDirection = "right";
                }                    
            }

            context.font = '20px _sans';
            context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
            context.textBaseline = 'top';
            context.fillText  ( text, textXpos, 180);    
          }    
          </script>
      </head>
      <body> 
         <div id="page">
            <canvas id="cvs" width="500" height="500">
               Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
            </canvas>
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/bS79G/

Comment: is JQuery really needed for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the canvas store(), translate() and restore() methods to animate the text. 
suppose if you want to move the text from right side to left side, then you can use the following code snippet:

Refer site: http://www.authorcode.com/text-animation-in-html5/

var can, ctx, step, steps = 0,
              delay = 20;

```
    function init() {
        can = document.getElementById("MyCanvas1");
        ctx = can.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.font = "20pt Verdana";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        step = 0;
        steps = can.height + 50;
        RunTextRightToLeft();
    }

    function RunTextRightToLeft() {
        step++;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(can.width / 2, step);
        ctx.fillText("Welcome", 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();
        if (step == steps)
            step = 0;
        if (step < steps)
            var t = setTimeout('RunTextRightToLeft()', delay);
    }
```