# How to make text that slides horizontally on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a text that slides horizontally on the screen, and the text mustn't stop moving. Here's what I have so far:

```js
setInterval(showQuote, 5000);

function showQuote() {
  $('.hey').fadeOut(function() {
    // remove visible class from old quote and add it to new
    // get next quote and fadeIn() when fadeout finishes
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hey">
  <blockquote>Quote goes here</blockquote>
  <p class="quoteBy">Author</p>
</div>

<div class="quote">
  <blockquote>Second Quote goes here</blockquote>
  <p class="quoteBy">Author</p>
</div>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: see that post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11450477/3687474

Comment: have you tried to archive your goal? there are plenty resources out there when you just basically search for "jQuery horizontal slide". you can archive your goal, by using jQuery.animate() or using css transitions.

Comment: Thank you man !!

Answer (score 0):

### Using pure CSS animations and some JS magic

I have made this with the help of *JQuery* and *Animate.css* **is it what you are looking for?**

You can visit the *Animate.css* library [here](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

***I have changed the original code a little bit.

```js
function animateElementsOneByOne(selector, action, interval) {
  var elements = $(selector).toArray();
  var index = 0;
  var timeout = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      action(elements[index]);
      if (index + 1 < elements.length) {
        index++;
        timeout();
      }
    }, interval);
  }
  if (elements.length > 0)
    timeout();
}

animateElementsOneByOne('.quote', function(element) {
  element.style.visibility = 'visible';
  $(element).addClass('animated slideInLeft');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.quote {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quote">
  <blockquote>
    <p>Quote goes here</p>
    <p class="quote-by">Author</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>

<div class="quote">
  <blockquote>
    <p>Second Quote goes here</p>
    <p class="quote-by">Author</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>

<div class="quote">
  <blockquote>
    <p>Third Quote goes here</p>
    <p class="quote-by">Author</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Did I answer correctly? You must mark the answer as accepted if that is the case. If not, please tell me how I can improve my answer.

Comment: In fact i want this to from right to left without stop moving .. and than again will appear in right to go again in left ..